# How to compile an independent executable file to MacOS from Windows in C++?

Tags: c++

I was working on this video game for my mom in VS19. My mom is across the internet and only uses a Macbook. I only use Windows. Does anyone know how I can build my C++ game to Mach-O executable format?

Answer (score 0):

To compile for MacOS you need the xcode toolset, but apple doesn't allow its use on any platform other than MacOS. One alternative is to install a virtual machine with MacOS installed on it. There are some tools which can cross compile, [such as this one](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross). But the first method is more reliable. Additionally, you could just send the source code.